# Request to GraphQL with only Queries without Fragments

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I want to request to GraphQL Server from Relay only Queries without Fragments. 
For example with simple relay app at the link: https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#/, this always post to GraphQL server a query inculde Fragments like that:

```
query GreetingsQuery {
    greetingsSchema {
        ...F0
    }
} 
fragment F0 on GreetingsQL {
    hello
}
```

But I just want to post a single query without any fragment inside, something like that:

```
query UserQuery {
    users() {
        id
        name
    },
}
```

Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can inline the entire query in your Relay user queries. No need for fragments. Also make sure you don't have an empty parentheses if you don't have query params.

Comment: Could you tell me more clear? With the thing I know about Container of Relay  , Container always declare the component's data requirements using fragments, some thing like that: 

    `module.exports = Relay.createContainer(Container-name, {
           fragments: {
                user: () => Relay.QL`
                      ....
                `,
           },
    }); 
    `


Any way to create queries in Component or Container without using Fragments?

Comment: Yes, so you technically don't need to create any fragments. You can leave that as an empty object literal in your Relay Container. As long as your user query defines the entire query, you should be fine. In other words, you don't need to dynamically pull in those fragments from the container on the fly with `${Component.getFragment('F0')}`. replace that with the hard-coded fragment fields right in line.